# How to increase the number of CPUs in my computer?

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-espresso, high-performance-computing, condensed-matter

I'm running my calculations using Quantum ESPRESSO on a 10th generation i7 computer (Dell) with Ubuntu.

When I run any calculation using the command `mpirun '/directory/ pw.x' -in  file.in> file.out`, only 8 processors are used. However the output of `nproc` gives me 16.

I want my calculations to run faster. How can I increase the number CPUs used? Is it safe to do that?

PS: I use the computer just for DFT calculations at the moment.

Comment: Exactly how are you running Quantum Espresso? How do you start it? And how many cores are in the machine you are using? To answer that if you are using Linux the output of `lscpu` would be useful, if relevant please edit the question to include it. I'm afraid I can't help you with Windows.

Comment: @IanBush I edited the question can you check it please?

Comment: The output of `nproc` is not that useful. Can you show us the output of `lscpu` as requested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Answer to the question in the title

> "How to increase the number of CPUs in my computer?"

You can either remove your current i7 [microprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microprocessor) from the [motherboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motherboard) and replace it with one that has more CPUs, or you could connect multiple motherboards together to form an HPC "cluster". You might find the following [high-performance-computing](/questions/tagged/high-performance-computing) threads useful if you're interesting in going in either of those directions:

- [Should I connect 2-3 laptops to form a supercomputer?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/6165/5)
- [Are there critical mistakes to avoid when creating a workstation (32-128 cores)?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/5018/5)
- [Suggestions on laptops for matter modeling](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/7151/5)
- [Should I buy a CPU or a GPU for doing calculations?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/883/5)
- [Materials Modeling with Raspberry Pi?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1125/5)
- [Is ARM64 the next big thing?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/2112/5)

However, the rest of your question suggests that the title was not chosen so accurately. It seems that you're not **trying to increase the number of CPUs in your computer** but you're trying to **make use of more of the CPUs that already exist in your comptuer.**

[Nick Papior's comment](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/10504/how-to-increase-the-number-of-cpu-in-my-computer#comment22437_10505) pointed out that if "8 processors are used" (as your question says), then you're already using all of your processors! This is because the Intel i7 microprocessor does something called [hyperthreading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading) which means that each core can have two threads, so 8 physical cores means a total of 16 possible threads.

## Is it safe to oversubscribe a computer?

> "How can I increase the number CPU used? Is it safe to do that?"

I do not recommend for you to oversubscribe your machine. Nick Papior's above-linked comment mentioned that you can use `--oversubscribe`, but it came with a big warning:

> "but please test for something simple to see if this actually gives you anything!!!!"

I want to add to that warning, not to just test if it gives you speed-up, **but also to test how safe this is: I wouldn't want you to crash your hardware**. In this question: [Is this "internal error" reproducible when compiling OpenMolcas on other Intel compilers?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/10211/5), I warned users not to even "fully subscribe" (let alone "over subscribe") a personal  computer. In that specific case of compiling OpenMolcas, the compilation took about 20 minutes when using 2 cores, but took more than an hour when using 4 cores (which also caused me a big scare because the entire computer froze during that hour, and the fan seemed overworked as if the computer was going to overheat and permanently damage CPU components).

## Conclusion

Welcome to the wonderful world of high-performance matter modeling :) It's really nice to have you in this community. Some of my greatest joys have been with doing calculations that gave me experiences like the one you're currently having. At some point we need to accept that we are doing the best we can with the resources that we have available, and we just need to find more resources (e.g. run the calculations on a supercomputer that has 1000s of cores), reduce the computational demands in the project (e.g. don't aim for such high accuracy), or wait longer for the calculations to run.

If you are open to the idea of jumping off the bicycle (8-core CPU) and hopping into a racecar (supercomputer with 1000s of cores), the following threads might be helpful for you (also I have over 1000 CPU years available in total in case you want to try some calculations here):

- [Supercomputers around the world](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1515/5)
- [Supercomputers around the world, which allow access for researchers outside the country](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1613/5)
- [What are some cloud services for computing?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/4635/5)
- [Solving the Schrödinger equation as a service?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/4702/5)

Comment: If your code is not well optimized, there might be something to gain from using both logical cores per physical core.  e.g. if you sum an array with simplistic code like `for(...) sum += arr[i];` and don't use `-ffast-math` to let the compiler unroll with multiple accumulators to hide FP latency.  Two threads per physical core would let the CPU interleave work of two dependency chains each bottlenecked on one add per 4 clock cycles (e.g. Skylake).  Of course, it's even better to optimize your code so one thread can mostly saturate its execution units and/or memory bandwidth.

Comment: Yeah, for most HPC work, you only want one thread per physical core.  But a good personal computer should have no problem running all cores, especially a desktop.  e.g. a prime95 stress test on my system (i7-6700k) gets my 4c8t machine up to 75C at 3.9GHz (EPP = `balance_performance`) or 80C at 4.0 GHz (`performance`), according to `sensors`.  (With "small" FFTs, otherwise it wants to allocate so much RAM that it's triggering the OOM killer :/)  At worst a non-broken system won't be able to turbo beyond its base frequency, which can be quite low in a laptop if there are many cores and low TDP.

Answer (score 6):

The specific details of how you are running QE are not clear. But here is a simple general overview of how to run QE in parallel settings.

If you are using `mpirun` command, then do the following:

`mpirun -np 8 pw.x < file.in > file.out`

Here, the `-np` switch specifies the number of processes of QE to start. You can increase it from 8 to as long as you are not oversubscribing. But make sure you have enough available processors. For other programs such as dos.x, bands.x, etc., the syntax remains the same. For windows, you might have to change `.x` to `.exe`. Also, if the standard input symbol  `<`  doesn't work, try `-inp` or `-in` or simply `-i`.

Also, you can specify the number of processors used in each group by adding additional switches (`-nk`, `-nb`, `-nd` etc). See [this user guide](https://www.quantum-espresso.org/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/user_guide.pdf) for details.

Comment: when i run a calculation I use the command `mpirun '/directory/ pw.x' -in  file.in>  file.out` and when I check the file.out i see that the calculations were performed using 8 processors. However when I type the command `nproc` in the terminal it gives me 16, means I have 16 processors. Am I right? If yes I don't know how to benefit from the remaining 8 processors

Comment: You can try the `-np 16` switch after `mpirun` to use all your 16 processing units

Comment: When I try to do that I get the following message in the terminal `There are not enough slots available in the system to satisfy the 9 slots that were requested by the application........`

Comment: This is because you have 16 processing units, but only 8 physical cores. Generally MPI checks for physical cores vs threads, and `nproc` gives you the threads. For `qe` you probably won't see a performance benefit from using the threads, but you can do so with `mpirun -np 16 --oversubscribe ...` (but please test for something simple to see if this actually gives you anything!!!!)

Comment: This conversation is also taking place [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/63091433#63091433).